# ImageView swipe animation from left to right & vice-versa

Tags: android, android-animation

How Can I implement the swipe animation from left-to-right & right-to-left on user touch's gesture.

Similar behavior is present in Tinder android application.

Comment: Have you considered a `ViewPager`?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the ViewPager in the Android API.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

It's pretty well documented on there, but possibly a little too involved for me to post a solution on here as such., especially without your code. Just put the ImageViews inside your Fragments.